# Skybox with OpenGL ES on iOS - NO GLKit + iOS 5.0

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es

Please give me some hint/source to build a skybox (like street view) in OpenGL ES...after a week I only found a post: [Skybox OpenGL ES iPhone and iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110893/skybox-opengl-es-iphone-and-ipad) but the link shared by Tommy is broken.

Comment: Rather than posting a new question, leave Tommy a comment indicating that the file in his answer no longer exists. He's very active here, and I'm sure he'd re-upload it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Skybox OpenGL ES iPhone and iPad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110893/skybox-opengl-es-iphone-and-ipad)

Comment: I added a comment for Tommy on [Skybox OpenGL ES iPhone and iPad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110893/skybox-opengl-es-iphone-and-ipad) but my post was deleted...so How can I contact him?

Comment: I forgot that you don't have the reputation required to leave comments. A comment as an answer isn't the right way to get a hold of someone here. I've left a comment on your behalf asking him to re-upload this.

Answer (score 2):

[The GLKit contains a SkyBox effect](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKSkyboxEffect_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010921). Example usage [here](https://github.com/jlamarche/iOS-OpenGLES-Stuff/tree/88ed7c7b2278a508084e40d135ff860107254d67/GLKit%20Stuff/GLKReflectionMapEffect%20&%20GLKSkybox%20Examples).

Note I'm not into iOS dev; just watched a WWDC session.

Comment: Yes I know that...but I'm searching examples in OpenGL ES 1.1 or 2.0 for compatibility with previous iOS (< 5.0).

Comment: My main problem is: how can I rotate on Y axis and then on X axis without have a tilted panorama? In other words, how can I perform rotations but maintain the original axis of rotation?

Comment: @GiovanniCatapano so you want your camera, as it were, to behave so that a swipe left or right always causes the view to rotate left or right — more like navigating a plane and ending up at any old angle than moving your head? I guess the main difference would be when you're looking directly 'up', when to the viewer it'd be between the view rotating around z and rotating around y. Also, I got Brad's message and am going to check whether I still have that Skybox sample when I get an opportunity.

Comment: @Tommy yes I search a skybox that simulate the camera movement of Street View...I tried to use CALayer and Core Animation 3D Transformation; the skybox was OK, if I rotate only on X or Y axis all was OK, the problem was the diagonal movement because axis change their reference. Then I tried with OpenGL ES but I didn't have the experience to develop with this technology.

Comment: My idea is to build a 6 face cube with texture and then rotate the camera not the world like I did with Core Animation...I only found an example of skybox in pure OpenGL [Apron tutorials on OpenGL](http://www.morrowland.com/apron/tut_gl.php) but I'm having great difficulties in converting the sources. My OpenGL ES base point is [Brad Larson's example](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/CubeExample.zip)